# What is value of $\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\ldots}}}}=$?

Tags: nested-radicals

My question: how to find nested radical having $n$th roots $$\large\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\ldots}}}}=?$$
My try:
$$\large\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\ldots}}}}=y$$
$$\large\sqrt[n]{xy}=y$$
$$\large xy=y^n$$$$ y^n-xy=0$$
Above $\mathrm{nth}$ degree equation should $n$ number of roots but my teacher says it has a unique value. I am totally confused how to get that value .

What will be the answer? I am looking for some trick or elegant way to solve such nested radical. Thanks

Comment: Hint: $y^n-xy=y(y^{n-1}-x)=0$

Comment: Why not $x=y^{n-1}\implies y=x^{1/(n-1)}$?  This just shows that it's the only possible value.  you still have to consider whether the sequence converges or not.

Comment: Here’s a hint.. consider writing this expression as x to some exponent. What would the exponent be, and is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: thanks, but shouldn't it have $n$ roots?

Comment: i am sorry there was a typo in my question. i fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a trick:
$$\large \sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\sqrt[n]{x\ldots}}}=x^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot x^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\cdot x^{\frac{1}{n^3}}\cdot\ldots=x^{\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\ldots\right)}=x^{\frac{\frac1n}{1-\frac1n}}=x^{\frac{1}{n-1}} $$

Comment: how did you get $\frac1n+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\ldots=\frac{1}{n-1}$?

Comment: @Jyerkimenon  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Comment: I don't like the haters. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just do this in the last line.
$$xy = y^n\iff \frac{y^n}{y} = y^{n-1} =x \iff \color{blue}{y = x^\frac{1}{n-1}}$$

Comment: it means you eliminated one $y$?

Comment: Yep, $\frac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b-c}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

I took $y$ common,
$$y^n-xy=0$$
$$y(y^{n-1}-x)=0$$
$$y=0, \ \ y^{n-1}-x=0$$
$$y=0, \ \ y=x^{\dfrac1{n-1}}$$
But $y\ne 0$, I get the answer

$$ y=x^{\dfrac1{n-1}}$$